# How to parse results from MySQL Table with PHP using row data?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Typically when I make calls into a mysql db, I reference a column for values I need. In this particular instance however, I need to retrieve a set of rows and parse with PHP accordingly. The example is this:

### Table format

```
ID   |   Level
-----------------
1    |    1
2    |    2
3    |    2
4    |    3
5    |    4
6    |    4
```

I am ultimately trying to retrieve all possible levels and count the number of results by those levels. A simple GROUP BY, COUNT() will do the trick:

```
'Select Level, Count(*) as counter FROM table GROUP BY Levels ORDER BY Levels ASC'
```

Which will return:

### table_new

```
Level  | Count
--------------
1     |   1
2     |   2
3     |   1
4     |   2
```

The problem I face though is when retrieving these results with PHP, I am not quite sure how to set a variable, say 'level1' and set it to the value returned in the count column.

I assume the logic would follow:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $count_level = $row['counter']
}
```

(but then I would need to create counts for each level type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$level = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $level[$row['level']] = $row['counter']
}
```

then you have `$level` array and `$level[1]`, `$level[2]` etc variables

Comment: makes sense. I've plugged in but not getting the same results my stored procedure returns. I'll check it out real quick again. It is strange but it is cutting off the final result.

Comment: level seems capitalized in your query. do you have your error reporting at E_ALL level?

Comment: yep - the query runs fine, the code seems to run fine too but the array built is only keeping track of the first N_total - 1 records. I'm still trouble shooting but your answer seems logical and correct.

Comment: don't you call `$stmt->fetch()` apart from the loop? that's pretty common mistake

Comment: good lord - I am an idiot. I have a cached session variable making the call from the level 2 player. My bad. Great support and answer. Thank for your help.

Comment: How do you know it's only `N_total - 1` records? Are you using `var_dump`?

Comment: @Robert Martin - I knew that because I can run the stored procedure directly in mysql gui. It is irrelevant in this case though because what I was entering in mysql gui was NOT the actual input the php was using.